# In a page, On dropdown select i need to get data in a table(table i should be able to edit)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, cascading

I am new to Sharepoint. I am using Sharepoint Designer 2013. Need pointers/sample code to accomplish the below.

I have to 2 custom Lists like below.
Ex: 
State (Custom list1)

```
State
AP
UP
MP
```

City (Custom list2)

```
City State Desc
KNR AP 
WL  UP
NZB AP
SRC MP
HZB UP
```

I have to create a page, where I have to load dropdown values from 1st list. When I selected the value from dropdown, I should get all the selected dropdown value related data from 2nd list
in a table/grid, where I have to edit the table and save.

Comment: try this https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using

Comment: Yes, you can try above link and actually it's called Cascaded dropdown.

Comment: Requirement is not Cascading, In a page, On dropdown select i need to get data in a table(table i should be able to edit)

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement you will need to use **List Filter WebPart**.

Steps are as below

1. Add a **City** list of a Page
2. Then add **List Filter Web Part** on page. Configure it to get data from **State** List
3. Connect filter web part to city list
4. Done

Now when you select state in Filter WebPart, city list will get auto-filtered to show cities belong to that state.

For detailed exploitation check below link. 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-Filter-Web-Part-to-a-List-View-Web-Part-4f3f6c10-0a1b-479d-8b4d-c4f1bf49bb3f

The above link has explanation of all filter webparts available. In your case, you will need to use SharePoint List filter webpart

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need SharePoint designer for this requirement. You can do this using javascript either in content editor webpart or using app

Comment: Requirement is not Cascading, In a page, On dropdown select i need to get data in a table(table i should be able to edit). I don't get any helpful links in online. If any pls share

Answer (score 0):

Probably this like will help you [OOTB Cascading Drop down in SharePoint online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/195644/ootb-cascading-drop-down-in-sharepoint-online)

You can do Cascading dropdown using SPServices library.