# calculated column IF OR

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, cascading-dropdown

I'd like to create a calculated column that helps me segregate options based on a previously selected choice. The essential argument will be the following that

- if the user selects `Alignment A` then his next choice will be option `1`, `2`, or `3`;
- if the user selects `Alignment B` then his next choice will be option `4`, `5`, `6`, or `7`;
- if the user selects `Alignment C` then his next choice will be option `8`, `9`, or `10`;
- if the user selects `Alignment D` then his next choice will be option `11`, `12`, or `13`;
- and if the user selects `Alignment E` then his next choice will be option `14` or `15`.

This may be a bit convoluted, but I essentially want to segregate their categorizations based on their previous choice, rather than allowing them to pick any of the options regardless of the previous choice. This will prevent user confusion when working through the site.

Comment: This is not what calculated columns are for. You are describing cascading dropdowns. Calculated columns are fields that are set using the values of other columns and have nothing to do with the form.

Comment: Thank you!! Now at least I know what I'm looking for. One of my coworkers is very adept at coding, so hopefully that will fit the bill.

Comment: As written above, you need cascade dropdown/choice columns. There are couple of questions on this site with similar/same topic. Example, this one https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/195644/cascading-drop-down-in-sharepoint-online/195645

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to look into SP Services.

[$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37676.sharepoint-2013-cascade-dropdown-list-using-spservices-spservices-spcascadedropdowns.aspx)

or build your own little JavaScript evaluation.